# Elasticsearch actual score is different explained score

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I ran a query in Elasticsearch with explain on. The final score from the explain is 7.0064363 but the actual score from the query is only 0.6251602.

What is Elasticsearch doing between the explanation and the actual score that's causing the score to be so different? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a snippet of the search results:

```
  {
    "_shard": 4,
    "_node": "KjOdjnQqQ-yQ3a0hvhlTcA",
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "id",
    "_score": 0.6251602,
    "_source": {
      .....
    },
    "_explanation": {
      "value": 7.0064363,
      "description": "product of:",
      "details": [
        {
          "value": 12.845133,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
          ........
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": 0.54545456,
          "description": "coord(6/11)",
          "details": []
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: I changed the number of shards of the index to 1 (down from the default of 5) and I don't see this problem anymore.

Shards do affect the score because Elasticsearch calculates IDF within a shard only by default. However, I did try adding the query parameter search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch but I still got the inconsistent scores, so I'm not sure if that was the cause.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html

Comment: I have the same problem. I changed the number of shards to 1 as explained above - nothing has changed.